# How to add .jar file dependencies to pom.xml file using m2eclipse plugin

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, pom.xml, m2eclipse

I would like to add junit 4.10 to my dependencies for my pom.xml and also 2 other denpencies found https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list 
and here https://code.google.com/p/mnist-tools/downloads/detail?name=mnist-tools.zip&can=2&q=

But I have no idea how to add them to the pom.xml file using the m2eclipse plugin

Also my file structure for my maven project can be found here: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

I was wondering if my file structure is going to be a problem? I do name all of my test classes like *Test.java For example ExampleClass.java has a corresponding file ExampleClassTest.java

This is my pom.xml file so far:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WalnutiQ</groupId>
  <artifactId>WalnutiQ</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>tests</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>train</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>images</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>tests</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there a special reason why you changed the [default maven folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) to something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is available in maven, so you can just add a dependency, see http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.code.gson|gson|2.2.4|jar, it has the snippet you need for your pom.

If `mnist-tools` isn't in a maven repo anywhere, you can add it to your local repo using `mvn install-file`.

Your structure probably looks like it would work (you tell us, does it?), but unless there's a good reason to change it, stick with the default structure maven uses. I.e. `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` etc. If I add more I usually try to keep them in the same structure e.g. `src/main/scripts`